# Excel VBA implement instrument control error

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use VBA to control optical instrument. At first i write all the objects & variant on thisworkbook , control function on module1 , UI control on userform1 .Public object shown as below. But i found objca can't work normally. So i guess it might be the issue of delivering object between thisworkbook , module1 , userform1.

```
Public objCa200 As Ca200
Public objca As Ca 
Public objprobe As probe
Public objmemory As Memoryter
```

After many times of trying , it can work normally with declared objects on module1 , control function on module1 , UI control on userform1. 
But i still don't understand why ??? Should object can be called by any userform or module if declare pubic object on thisworkbook??

Comment: You can call module functions and variables by prepending the variable/function with the module name. For example: `Module1.Ca200` http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/425695-global-vs-public-variable.html

Comment: I would think VB (or VB.NET) would be a better option for this than VBA. VBA is tailored to work with MS Office products and some of the things you may need to do might be significantly more difficult in VBA

Answer (score 0):

Although its not completely obvious, the **Excel Objects** section is supposed to be used typically for Excel Events, not for general subroutines and functions.  That includes the "ThisWorkbook" object; that is for Excel Events that are triggered for the entire workbook (aka Excel file).

You *can* place general functions and subroutines into an Excel Objects object, but you will have to prefix calls to that function or sub with the object name [ e.g. Sheet1.functionInSheet1(...) ].  It does not however make sense to put a subroutine or function that needs to be used by multiple sheets into just one of the named sheets; that will confuse both you at a later date, or someone else that needs to use or adapt your Excel file.

**Modules** is the section where typically all your worker functions and subroutines go.  That includes functions that may be invoked by cell formulas, and includes subroutines that may be invoked by UI controls.  These functions and subroutines are accessible to all sheets and charts in the Excel file.  Assuming you only have one Module defined and no duplicated names of the subroutines/functions, you will not have to prefix any calls to these subs/functions.

This scoping is independent of the public/private designator.

A very detailed write-up about scoping is at the link below. Scroll down to the "*Placement of Macros/ Sub procedures in appropriate Modules*" section:
http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=162:excel-vba-calling-sub-procedures-a-functions-placement-in-modules&catid=79&Itemid=475